# how to use fileupload insert to database sql server this

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim filePath As String = FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim filePath2 As String = FileUploadImage.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fileName)
    Dim contenttyppe As String = String.Empty
    Select Case ext
        Case ".pdf"
            ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Exit Select
        Case ".jpg"
            ContentType = "image/jpg"
            Exit Select
        Case ".pfx"
            ContentType = "image/pfx"
            Exit Select
        Case ".png"
            ContentType = "image/png"
            Exit Select
        Case ".gif"
            ContentType = "image/gif"
            Exit Select
        Case ".doc"
            ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
            Exit Select
        Case ".docx"
            ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
            Exit Select
        Case ".xls"
            ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Exit Select
        Case ".xlsx"
            ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Exit Select
        Case ".pfx"
            ContentType = "image/pfx"
            Exit Select
    End Select
    If contenttyppe <> String.Empty Then
        Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream
        Dim fi As Stream = FileUploadImage.PostedFile.InputStream
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim br2 As New BinaryReader(fi)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
        Dim bytes2 As Byte() = br2.ReadBytes(fi.Length)
        Dim strQuery As String = "insert into APPUSERDTL (UID,APPCODE,APPEXPIRED,SIGNIMAGE, PFKFILE,HEADUID,PRINCIPALFROM,PRINCIPALTO,EXCEPTIONUSER,LastUpdate)" _
                            & "VALUES('',' ','','  @FileUpload  ','  @FileUploadImage','','','','','')"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UID", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@APPCODE", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@APPEXPIRED", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileUpload", Data.SqlDbType.Image).Value = FileUpload
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileUploadImage", Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = FileUploadImage
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HEADUID", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRINCIPALFROM", Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRINCIPALTO", Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EXCEPTIONUSER", Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = bytes
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bytes
        InsertUpdateData(cmd)

        lblMsgUpload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        lblMesgImage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        lblMsgUpload.Text = "File Upload Successfully"
        lblMesgImage.Text = "File Upload Successfuly"

    Else
        lblMesgImage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMesgImage.Text = "File format not recognised." _
         & " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats"
    End If

    ' delete file upload
    Dim fullPath = MapPath("~/upload/") + fileName
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

==================================================

```
Public Function InsertUpdateData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
    '  Dim strConnString As New DBX
    Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Ok, you have posted all that you have. Is it working?

Comment: not working brotha..can't execute (strQuery)..please help me

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: not exception brotha..i'am already make store procedure not exec also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only two parameters placeholders in the query text (`@FileUpload` and `@FileUploadImage`). Then you define parameters for every field with various datatype, but then set them all with the same value (`bytes`). Finally the commas that should separe the values are placed wrongly in the query text.  No wonder that you ExecuteNonQuery doesn't work

If you don't know the other values and your record could be inserted leaving that fields to their default value you could try with this trimmed down version of your query above. Otherwise you need to know the actual values to insert in the other fields and initialize the parameters value with the appropriate variables.

Dim strQuery As String = "insert into APPUSERDTL (SIGNIMAGE,PKFILE,LastUpdate) " & _
                            "VALUES(@FileUpload,@FileUploadImage, GetDate())"

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileUpload", Data.SqlDbType.Image).Value = FileUpload
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileUploadImage", Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = FileUploadImage
InsertUpdateData(cmd)
```

As a last note, when you have errors it is always good to add the error message to your question. It is very helpfull to understand what happens in your code.

Comment: I just wanted to update 2 fields that alone, @ FileUploadImage and @ Fileimage in table appuserdtl

Comment: You are using an INSERT INTO, not an UPDATE, your code inserts a new record in the table. If the table accepts a new record without all the other fields define (AllowNull) then you don't need to pass them

Comment: thanks master steve..thanks for its support..I have much more to learn...please guidance